# Zermelo's Proof of the Well Ordering Theorem

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, well-orders

I am trying to find the paper by Zermelo in the early 1900's in which he proved the Well Ordering Theorem (implicitly using the axiom of choice). Does anyone know where I can find this?

Comment: This probably belongs on hsm.se.

Comment: @J.G. What is that?

Comment: https://hsm.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> English versions of Zermelo’s papers are in
>
> J. van Heijenoort (ed.), From Frege to Gödel - A Source Book in Mathematical Logic 1879-1931 , Harvard UP 1967.

https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-ordering+theorem